# Select duplicate payment pending orders with no corresponding paid order

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is:

orders

```
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| id   | customer_id | payment_status |   created_on| 
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1    |      1      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-28  |
| 2    |      1      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 3    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 4    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 5    |      4      |      paid      | 2018-12-30  |
| 6    |      3      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-30  |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

order_items

```
+------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+
| id   | order_id  |  product_id | quantity | price |
+------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+
| 1    |   1       |      4      |  2       | 20.50 |
| 2    |   1       |      5      |  2       | 25.00 |
| 3    |   2       |      4      |  2       | 20.50 |
| 4    |   2       |      5      |  2       | 25.00 |
| 5    |   3       |      1      |  1       | 20.00 |
| 6    |   3       |      2      |  1       | 25.00 |
| 7    |   4       |      1      |  1       | 20.00 |
| 8    |   4       |      2      |  1       | 25.00 |
| 9    |   5       |      4      |  2       | 20.50 |
| 10   |   5       |      5      |  2       | 25.00 |
| 11   |   6       |      3      |  4       | 15.00 |
+------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+
```

customer

```
+-----+---------------+----------+
| id  | email         |  name    |
+-----+---------------+----------+
| 1   | abc@mail.com  |  user 1  |
| 2   | xyz@mail.com  |  user 2  |
| 3   | pqr@mail.com  |  user 3  |
| 4   | abc@mail.com  |  user 4  |
+-----+---------------+----------+
```

Q: I want the data as orders which are under one customer email with pending status and no paid status orders under that customer with in a week

Expected output: 1
single order with no corresponding paid order with in a week

```
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| id   | customer_id | payment_status |   created_on| 
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| 3    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 4    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 6    |      3      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-30  |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Q: I want the data as if there are 2 orders which has same products and same quantity under one customer email with pending status and no paid status orders under that customer with in a week

Expected output: 2
two orders with no corresponding paid order with in a week

```
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| id   | customer_id | payment_status |   created_on| 
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| 3    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
| 4    |      2      |      unpaid    | 2018-12-29  |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please post your actual SQL as text in your question.

Comment: @ThomasG, I have updated the question, Please check

Comment: "with in a week" -- "within a week of ordering"? or "since a week ago"?

Answer (score 2):

The first query is dubious -- Did you really mean `email` or `customer_id`?  The latter *should* be how you designed the schema to distinguish one "customer" from another.  Think that through.  (And fix the data to make it clear.)  Meanwhile, I will assume `customer_id` distinguishes customers.

I can't wrap my head around the *purpose* of the first query.  You are looking for customers that paid for a later Order, but have not paid for an earlier order?  Or looking for mis-postings in the database?  Anyway, here is a shot at it:

```
SELECT  Unpd.id, Unpd.customer_id, Unpd.payment_status, Unpd.created_on
    FROM  Orders AS Pd  ON Pd.customer_id = C.id
      AND  payment_status = 'paid'
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  1
            FROM  Orders AS Pd
            WHERE  Pd.customer_id = C.id
              AND  Pd.payment_status = 'paid'
              AND  Pd.created_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
    )
```

Second query.  I rephrase it as: Locate two (or more) orders (paid or unpaid) by the same customer ON the same day (but not checking that the items are the same):

```
SELECT  O2.id, O2.customer_id, O2.payment_status, O2.created_on
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  O.customer_id, O.created_on
            FROM  Orders AS O
            GROUP BY  O.customer_id, O.created_on
            HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
    ) AS MultipleInOneDay
    JOIN  Orders AS O2  USING (customer_id, created_on)
```

Comment: Did you really mean email or customer_id? = > yes email ;

each time a new order get placed new customer also created even if the customer is present in the database( i agree db need normalization but, I am convening them, but they are not ready to take changes :-( 

currently need to built 2 filters 
1) same email same products same quantity  with in last week (fund unpaid orders under an email if no paid order under that email in the given time with same products and quantity) kind of duplicate order

Comment: Putting off the schema cleanup is more costly in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely with Rick about cleaning up the schema

If I've read you correctly, currently your `customer` table effectively just adds the columns `email` and `name` to your `orders` table

---

**Q1**

Assuming you want within a week of today's date and ID fields cannot be null

```
SELECT ou.*
  FROM orders ou /** orders unpaid */
  JOIN customer cu /** customer unpaid */
    ON cu.id = ou.customer_id
 WHERE ou.payment_status = 'unpaid'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
       FROM orders op /** orders paid */
       JOIN customer cp /** customer paid */
         ON cp.id = op.customer_id
      WHERE op.payment_status = 'paid'
        AND op.created_on > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK /** or >= if required */
        AND cp.email = cu.email 
   )
```

**N.B.** As it is more than a week since the paid orders in your examples, you will have to adjust the temporal condition to see the same results

---

**Q2**

Same assumptions as Q1, plus assumption that a `product_id` can only appear once per order

```
SELECT ou.*
  FROM orders ou /** orders unpaid */
  JOIN customer cu /** customer unpaid */
    ON cu.id = ou.customer_id
  JOIN (  
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(oudc.id) orders_csv
      FROM (
        SELECT oui.id,
               cui.email,
               GROUP_CONCAT(oiui.product_id ORDER BY oiui.product_id) products,
               GROUP_CONCAT(oiui.quantity ORDER BY oiui.product_id) quantity
          FROM orders oui /** orders unpaid internal */
          JOIN customer cui /** customer unpaid internal */
            ON cui.id = oui.customer_id
          JOIN order_items oiui /** order items unpaid internal */      
            ON oiui.order_id = oui.id
         WHERE oui.payment_status = 'unpaid'   
      GROUP BY oui.id,
               cui.email
           ) oudc /** orders unpaid dupe check */
  GROUP BY oudc.email, 
           oudc.products, 
           oudc.quantity
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 /** or >=2 if required */   
       ) oud /** orders unpaid dupes */
    ON FIND_IN_SET(ou.id, oud.orders_csv) > 0
 WHERE ou.payment_status = 'unpaid'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
       FROM orders op /** orders paid */
       JOIN customer cp /** customer paid */
         ON cp.id = op.customer_id
      WHERE op.payment_status = 'paid'
        AND op.created_on > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK /** or >= if required */
        AND cp.email = cu.email 
   )
```

**N.B.** As it is more than a week since the paid orders in your examples, you will have to adjust the temporal condition to see the same results

This query is only roughly tested and is probably woefully slow. I suggest you run each nested select query individually (starting at the deepest) to see what is happening. Basically it concatenates the orders into 1 row each, then concatenates duplicate orders with the same email into 1 row each, then checks for orders in this row using a similar logic to Q1

If you can have the same `product_id` more than once per order, you can normalize with a further nested grouping select within my `orders unpaid dupe check` subquery

---

**SQLfiddle**

I have also [created an SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95fc38/1) to demonstrate these 2 queries in action on your example data. I have, however, adjusted the dates of the example orders so that they depend on the current date